# What is the variance of sixes that appear when a 1-6 die is rolled 1000 times?

Tags: probability

So I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around variances...

I calculated $\mathbf{E}[X]$ as $\frac{1000}{6}$, but that's the easy part. To calculate the variance, I'm trying to calculate the variance of a single roll, and then multiply that by $1000^2$, but I'm getting a weird number for that. I calculate the variance of a single roll with
$$\mathbf{E}[X^2] - \mathbf{E}[X]^2$$ which equals
$$\left(0^2\cdot\tfrac56 + 1^2\cdot\tfrac16\right) - \left(\tfrac16\right)^2 = \frac{5}{36}$$

But that multiplied by $1000^2$ is some unreasonably huge number. Is there another approach I should be trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: If $X$ is the number of sixes rolled, then $X$ is a random variable following the Binomial distribution.

Comment: Ah god you're totally right. I guess I thought too hard on this one!

Comment: Rest assured, though, that you were on the right track with your method. Each roll is a Bernoulli trial with probability of success $\frac{1}{6}$. Your calculated value of $\frac{5}{36}$ was the correct variance for one roll. Now since each roll is assumed to be independent, we get the variance for 1000 rolls is
$$\underbrace{\frac{5}{36}+\frac{5}{36}+\dotsb+\frac{5}{36}}_{\text{1000 times}} = \frac{5000}{36}.$$